# GMSMapView always display the same location iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

as the title says no matter what coordinates I give I see the same location.

Here is my code:

I am using storyboard and I have a subview inside my view. The subview is of type GMSMapView, and correctly linked.

.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet GMSMapView *mymap;
```

.m

```
@implementation DealViewController
{
    GMSMapView *mapView_;
}


@synthesize mymap=_mymap;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.8683
                                                            longitude:151.2086
                                                                 zoom:6];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300) camera:camera];
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled  = YES;
    mapView_.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite;
    mapView_.delegate = self;
    self.mymap=mapView_;

}
```

I also tried this, but I get the same:

```
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
```

What is wrong with the above?

Comment: is this issue resolved? if you are seeing a location in Europe(showing UK, France, etc), then it is the default map location that is shown when the map is initialised as `mapView_ = [[GMSMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];`  without mentioning any camera position. So your camera position setting is not working.

Comment: @tony not it is not resolved, but I used the default map kit in IOS instead of google maps. Thanks, I will check it out.

Comment: check is this [earlier post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059123/using-the-google-maps-sdk-in-views-other-than-the-main-view) is useful

Comment: did you find an answer?

Answer (score 11):

After hours of cruel research of the same problem I've found that viewDidLoad method should looks like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:obj.latitude
                                 longitude:obj.longitude
                                 zoom:12];
    self.mapView.camera = camera;
}
```

In other words in this case you should NOT assign any value (like '[GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300) camera:camera];') to self.mapView, just set it's property 'camera' value.

This works for me. I hope this will save time for someone else too.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using storyboards make sure you have set the type of the view to be a GMSMapView in the storyboard UI.

Then all you should need to do is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.8683
                                                            longitude:151.2086
                                                                 zoom:6];
    self.mymap.camera = camera;
    self.mymap.myLocationEnabled  = YES;
    self.mymap.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite;
    self.mymap.delegate = self;
}
```

There is a storyboard example that is available on the [Google Maps github page.](https://github.com/googlemaps/hellomap-ios/tree/master/HelloMapStoryboard)

Comment: the subview is of type GMSMapView but the view is of type UIVIew. Do you mean also the view to be of type GMSMapView?

Comment: This answer helped me to create a map referencing a GMSMapView on .xib and using autolayout.

Comment: @skarE can we provide address string to GMSCameraPosition instead of lat/long

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your problem:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet GMSMapView *mymap;

@implementation DealViewController
{
    GMSMapView *mapView_;
}

@synthesize mymap=_mymap;

mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300) camera:camera];
```

Your map is coming in from your storyboard, called `mymap`. You create an instance variable called `mapView_` **but** you synthesize `mymap` to `_mymap`...which is different.

Rather than using an instance variable, just access the property directly. Replace all the `mapView_` instances with `self.mymap`.

For example:

```
self.mymap = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300) camera:camera];
```

As to why it doesn't move to the user's location - here's what the Google Maps iOS SDK documentation has to say about the `myLocationEnabled` property:

> `myLocationEnabled` - Controls whether the My Location dot and accuracy circle is enabled.

...what it *doesn't* do is move the map to the current user's location. It only shows the user's location dot and circle on the map.

Your map is always displaying the same location because you never change it. You create a camera set to (-33.8683, 151.2086), ask the map to show the user's location indicator, but don't ask the map to *change* its location to that of the user.

To do this you can use the map's `myLocation` property to obtain the current location of the user, and then the `animateToLocation` method to move the map accordingly.

Comment: in the google maps documentation, when the above code is used (ignore the myLocationEnabled) it should give me the area around Singapore and not in Europe. No matter what coordinates I give, the camera gives me the same location (centred somewhere around Europe) and I do not see the marker at all.

Comment: Sydney with those coords, surely, not Singapore?

Comment: yes in the above example, I should see Sydney. i have tried also with Singapore's but in both cases I see an area in Europe with no marker.

Comment: I think I've figured it out. Your instance variable synthesis isn't right. I'm going to edit my answer above with some more info at the top.

Comment: thanks for the try but unfortunately nothing changes. If it makes any difference, I have also added code for identifying the tapping but this is not working as well, i do not see the log messages. It is like my map is not responding and just give me the default mapview.

Answer (score 0):

`GMSMapView` seems to struggle fitting to `GMSCoordinateBounds` in these situations:

1) You init the `GMSMapView` with a `.zero` frame

2) The `GMSMapView` is not yet visible on the screen

3) The `GMSMapView` is a subview of any given `UIViewController`

In any of these three cases you have to set the camera explicitly:

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: B.center, zoom: 19)
self.map.camera = camera
```