# Google Maps SDK not displaying properly in UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I'm having some problems displaying google maps in Xcode 6.1

I managed to get the map to display in a section of my UIView, but it displays the world map instead of at a particular coordinate.

Here is the issue:

[image]

.h:

```
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *googleMapView;

- (IBAction)mapToMain:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude: 32.915134 
    longitude: -117.140269 zoom: 17];

    GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.googleMapView.bounds
    camera:camera];
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;

    self.googleMapView = mapView;

    GMSMarker *marker = [ [GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(32.915134, -117.140269);
    marker.title = @"Tet Festival 2015";
    marker.snippet = @"VAYA Tet";
    marker.map = mapView;
}
```

I saw some suggestions here, but it didn't work:

[Cannot put a google maps GMSMapView in a subview of main main view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417811/cannot-put-a-google-maps-gmsmapview-in-a-subview-of-main-main-view)

[Using the Google Maps SDK in views other than the main view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059123/using-the-google-maps-sdk-in-views-other-than-the-main-view)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured it out...

removed:

```
self.googleMapView = mapView;
```

replaced:

```
[self.googleMapView addSubview:mapView];
```

Answer (score 12):

You have to add a UIView to your Storyboard... but after that you have to turn this simple UIView into a GMSMapView! Select the view you just added and open the Identity Inspector by selecting the third tab from the left in the Utilities toolbar, change the view’s class name from UIView to GMSMapView, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Your Outlet will not be like this

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *googleMapView;
```

it will be like this

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet GMSMapView *mapView;
```

Your ViewDidLoad can be like this:

```
 GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude: 32.915134
                                                            longitude: -117.140269 zoom: 17];

    [self.mapView animateToCameraPosition:camera];

    GMSMarker *marker = [ [GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(32.915134, -117.140269);
    marker.title = @"Tet Festival 2015";
    marker.snippet = @"VAYA Tet";
    marker.map = self.mapView;
```

UPDATE

[Here you have an example project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19438780/GoogleMaps-iOS-1.8.1-test%20autolayout%202.zip) (insert your Key)

Comment: Thanks! The same problem exists and Swift. MUST need to change the Custom Class of UIView

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is wrong with the code above. It looks fine for me. But to move the camera to certain location. You can animate the camera there as well.

```
var newLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
googleMapView.animateToLocation(newLocation)
```

Hope that it works for you.

Comment: I am basically trying to make the map display the marker location, but it's displaying the world map instead.

Comment: Can anyone else help? I searched SO and still cannot get this to work :(