# Why doesn't Google Maps stretch to fit my UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps

I have created a UIView that I would like to put google maps in. However, when I add GMSMapview to my UIView, the bottom portion of the GMSMapview does not extend to fit the UIView. I can still see the gray part of my UIVIew.

Why is that?

[image]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
    // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.868
                                                            longitude:151.2086
                                                                 zoom:6];
    GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.googleMapView.bounds camera:camera];



    [self.googleMapView addSubview:mapView];
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect your interface isn't necessarily sized for an iPhone 6 so when you set the `mapView` frame in `viewDidLoad`, although it initially fits inside your `googleMapView`, after auto layout occurs, the `googleMapView` stretches to fit the screen and the `mapView` stays the same size, which is too small.

To fix this, I suggest moving your code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews:` so your `mapView` frame is set after the `googleMapView` has stretched to fill the screen, ex:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.868
                                                            longitude:151.2086
                                                                 zoom:6];
    GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.googleMapView.bounds camera:camera];
    [self.googleMapView addSubview:mapView];
}
```

Comment: thank you lyndsey, I marked yours as the solution. Can you please look at my other post regarding Google Maps? No one seems to know the issue :( thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26772521/why-is-google-maps-sdk-not-working-on-iphone-6-ios-8

Answer (score 0):

If you are having this issue on Xcode 7, what worked for me (the accepted answer wasn't applicable to me since I am developing in Swift) was checking the 'Autoresize Subviews' box for both the `GMSMapView` and its parent (which for me was a `UIStackView`).

Answer (score 0):

Add the layout in side **viewDidAppear**

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
        super.viewDidAppear(animated) 
        //google map setup here
    }
```