# App rejected when used Google Maps SDK in Tabs

Tags: ios, sdk, maps

i have a one mistake when i used the Google Maps SDK, in the crash log send me mark error when the frame is create in the method DidViewLoad, i cant fund a solution. Help me please!.

Apple has a 64 bits device.
The code:

```
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.bounds camera:camera];
```

The crash log:

```
{"app_name":"HIVEBOP","app_version":"1.0.3","bundleID":"com.cidnucleo.HIVEBOP","adam_id":931528641,"os_version":"iPhone OS 8.1.1 (12B435)","slice_uuid":"9a8f8063-bca7-319d-814d-c369ff8c1dde","share_with_app_devs":false,"build_version":"1.0.3","is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","name":"HIVEBOP"}
Incident Identifier: CA0928EE-C1BE-4385-8CEA-EAB09B8FE56D
CrashReporter Key:   6d9ada58c53e88aace78cf026d7f9c20e062425c
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             HIVEBOP [822]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/2B2147B1-8ED5-472D-A182-9ABA70683939/HIVEBOP.app/HIVEBOP
Identifier:          com.cidnucleo.HIVEBOP
Version:             1.0.3 (1.0.3)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-11-24 17:12:56.361 -0800
Launch Time:         2014-11-24 17:12:55.929 -0800
OS Version:          iOS 8.1.1 (12B435)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x18641a59c 0x1862f4000 + 1205660
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x196f900e4 0x196f88000 + 32996
2   CoreFoundation                  0x186421664 0x1862f4000 + 1234532
3   CoreFoundation                  0x18641e418 0x1862f4000 + 1221656
4   CoreFoundation                  0x186322b6c 0x1862f4000 + 191340
5   HIVEBOP                         0x10027454c -[GMSMapView setCamera:] + 116
6   HIVEBOP                         0x100272eb8 -[GMSMapView sharedInitWithServices:camera:] + 1696
7   HIVEBOP                         0x10027223c -[GMSMapView initWithFrame:camera:] + 144
8   HIVEBOP                         0x1002720d4 +[GMSMapView mapWithFrame:camera:] + 116
9   HIVEBOP                         0x1000df0e0 -[MapaController viewDidLoad] (MapaController.m:566)
```

Thanks, regards.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26778538/1702413

Comment: Thanks, i'll tell you if your answer is correct.

Comment: Glad to help you! You can upvote the answer from link :)

Comment: i don't have any reputation points, upvote my question so i can give you upvote, regards :(