# Display google map in particular view

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, uiview, resize

I want the google maps to be displayed in only half of the screen and there are other items to be displayed in other half of the screen. So, I have divided the iPhone screen into two UIViews, **mapView** and **detailView**. When i try to have the google map inside mapView, it gives blank screen. Whereas It display map in the whole screen when it is assigned to self.view as follow.

**doesn't show in mapView**

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                        longitude:151.20
                                                             zoom:6];
GMSMapView *mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
self.mapView = mapView_; //Doesn't work

// Creates a marker in the center of the map.
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
marker.title = @"Sydney";
marker.snippet = @"Australia";
marker.map = mapView_;
```

Comment: I think the problem is in this line **[GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];**. You have to give frame to google map

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26778538/1702413

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
GMSMapView *mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
```

To this:

```
   GMSMapView *mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.mapView.frame camera:camera];
```

That should fix your problem, if you've set up the separate view appropriately and should match to that views frame.